# List of Paypal payments with personal Account

Tags: php, paypal

I have a Paypal Account Type: **Personal**

I don't want to be **Business account** or anything else.

Is there a way to get a **list of last payments** ? Maybe there is some **API for personal account** ?

*The only way I see to get what I want, is create a php script which will imitate browser, login to web, go to History and get the last payments.*

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only get access to the APIs using a premier or business account. 
As for a PHP script - you can certainly get it to work. 
However, if you do not take care of simulating a browser access 100%, PayPal **MAY** detect an unauthorized account access and lock the account down.

My advice would be to upgrade to a premier account and avoid the hacks.

Once you've got a premier account, you can use the TransactionSearch and GetTransactionDetails API calls in order to retrieve a list of payments (note that this can be a bit of a headache to handle too)

Comment: agreed no real down side upgrading your account - and trying to scape paypal is a terrible idea.