# Fetching new PayPal transactions for a Personal Account

Tags: paypal

I own a ***personal*** PayPal account and am coming up with the design for a personal financing application.  I intend to use the APIs provided by PayPal to fetch recent activity on my account to automate some of the information entry (at the moment, most of my transactions go through PayPal).

I've rooted through the API documentation, and I haven't been able to find any sort of endpoint I could use to fetch my recent account history.

I did find [a question previously asked and answered about two years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20129627/list-of-paypal-payments-with-personal-account) stating that the only way to do this was by getting a Premier account, which I'd rather avoid due to not knowing if there's any costs associated with such.  I'd also like to note that despite my Personal status, I still get notifications on my Android phone stating that I've spent money.

Which brings me to the title question: does PayPal's API expose some endpoint I missed that allows me (the user) to programmatically browse my history, find new transactions, and mark them down with little input from me, or at the very least register to receive notice from PayPal that a new transaction has appeared?

Comment: Premiere accounts no longer exist.  Just Personal or Business.  Upgrading to a business account does not cost anything.

Comment: Is there any stipulation on getting a business account? IE, have to at least sell *something*?

Comment: Nope, there's really nothing different about it except that you would save more money on fees if you do start selling more stuff, and it gives you access to more APIs.  That said, I think the APIs I mention in my answer are available to Personal accounts, although I have not specifically tested that.

Answer (score 0):

You can pull transaction history using the [TransactionSearch](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/TransactionSearch_API_Operation_NVP/) API.  Then you can get individual transaction details using [GetTransactionDetails](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetTransactionDetails_API_Operation_NVP/).

You may also want to look into [IPN](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/), which will automatically POST transaction data to a URL you specify as a listener.  That listener can receiver the data from PayPal and update your own database, send custom email notifications, hit 3rd party web services, etc.